# Override serializer field from child serializer Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Let's say I have two serializers, `UserSerializer` and `EmployeeSerializer`. Where Employee extends User. I want to override a field that is currently declared within UserSerializer from EmployeeSerializer.

From my understanding, you could achieved this via extra_kwargs, but it doesn't seem to work in my case and still getting required field error when I try to `POST` data to the server.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=20, allow_blank=False, allow_null=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"


class EmployeeSerializer(UserSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {
            'username': {'required': False}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extends `EmployeeSerializer` from `UserSerializer` and in `UserSerializer` you have explicitly declared the `username` field is required `True`. Thus you can't make it `required: False` in extra_kwargs dict, in fact it will not work as Django rest framework documentation says,

> Please keep in mind that, if the field has already been explicitly declared on the serializer class, then the extra_kwargs option will be ignored.

check [this link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) for elaborate understanding.

Comment: whoops, don't know how did i missed that bit in the docs. Thanks for quoting it btw. If i want to achieve the describe function. how should i write the serializer?

Comment: If you want to make `username` non required, then remove explicit declaration of username field from your `UserSerializer`.